# Why do i need explicitly use self-type in the given example?

Tags: scala, inheritance, types, self-type, upperbound

While reading and trying to get all the concepts behind scalable components in Scala from [this](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~odersky/papers/ScalableComponent.pdf), i still can't fully understand why this example should have self type:

```
abstract class Graph {
  type Node <: NodeLike
    trait NodeLike {    // without self: Node => won't compile
      def connectWith(n: Node) =
    new Edge(this, n)
    }           
    class Edge(from: Node, to: Node)
}
```

abstract type `Node` is a subtype of `NodeLike` and `this` is an object of type `NodeLike`  which suites according to the given upper constraint. Any detailed explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Well it rightly fails because of the bound `Node <: NodeLike`. When you are doing       `new Edge(this,n)`, you are simply passing argument types as `NodeLike, Node` to Edge. But your `Edge` expects 'Node,Node`:

```
class Edge(from: Node, to: Node)
```

i.e. you are trying to pass `NodeLike` to `Node` (NodeLike is super type of Node). Thats like passing an Animal to a function that is expecting Dog (The issue, is if it is allowed then you could pass any Animal including cat to one expecting Dog)

A work around would be :

```
abstract class Graph {
    type Node <: NodeLike
    trait NodeLike { // without self: Node => won't compile
      def connectWith(n: Node) =
        new Edge(this, n)
    }
    class Edge(from: NodeLike, to: Node)
  }
```

Or another way would be as you have mentioned where you explicitly guarantee that the argument you are passing is of type Node and not NodeLike.

Answer (score 0):

In the definition

```
def connectWith(n: Node) = new Edge(this, n)
```

`this` has type `NodeLike`, however the constructor for `Edge` requires that `from` is of type `Node`, which is a subtype of `NodeLike`. You need the self type annotation to ensure that `this` has the required type of `Node`.